# Give (in terms of orthonormal basis ) a vector in a given Span

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal, change-of-basis, orthogonal-matrices

I don't know how to do these "Give in terms of $(u_1,u_2, \ldots)$ a vector in Span (...) questions. I don't understand why $b$ and $c$ in the image below are done differently or why we have to set the linear combination to $0$ etc. Does this have anything to do with a change of basis? If someone could just give a very thorough explanation of the concepts behind $b$ and $c$ of this question, I would be eternally grateful !!

[Image of question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYkXI.jpg)

[Their Answers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WXRu0.png)

Comment: I'm having trouble following your questions. I think it would help if you explained the picture. This appears to be an exam (past exam?) with solutions written down. I notice a pen and a pencil have been used. Out of what has been written, what did you write? If you wrote all of it, how much of these solutions were written by you? Does the black pen ink mark your questions for us?

Comment: @Theo Bandit Yeah, so sorry, I was just going through it on my own and the black is just comments for myself. There were past solutions, which I've added to the problem now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **span** is a set of all linear combination of some vectors. The paper says $Span(\left\{\vec{v}_i\right\})$ where $\left\{\vec{v}_i\right\}$ is a set of vectors $\vec{v}_1,\vec{v}_2,..$. That means the span contains any vector $\vec{v}=a_1\cdot \vec{v}_1+a_2\cdot \vec{v}_2+..$ for any values $a_1, a_2,..$

**In terms of** means 'using those terms' (referring to the unit vectors $\vec{u}_1,\vec{u}_2,..$ in the paper). So you use those vectors in your answer.

In **problem (b)**, notice that the span lists just one vector
$$\vec{v}_1=\vec{u}_1+2\vec{u}_2+2\vec{u}_3$$
that happens to be a linear combination of several unit vectors.

Then all you have to do is find $a_1 \cdot \vec{v}_1$ which satisfies the constraint, a unit vector. That means a vector whose length is 1. You can convert a vector into a unit vector of the same orientation by dividing it by its original length. Length is computed using $l^2$-norm.

In **problem (c)**, notice that the span lists three vectors separated by commas. And also notice the perpendicular sign $\perp$. That means the span actually includes all vectors that are perpendicular (orthogonal) to any linear combinations of those three vectors.

For two non-zero vectors to be orthogonal, their dot product must be 0.

To find a vector that meets the criteria, define a non-zero vector $$\vec{v}=a_1\vec{u}_1+a_2\vec{u}_2+a_3\vec{u}_3+a_4\vec{u}_4$$, dot-product it with one vector of some arbitrary linear combination of the three vectors in the span list, and equate that to 0 to make it orthogonal. Then solve for $a_1,a_2,..$.

The paper is confusing because it interchangeably used $a,b,c$, $u_1,u_2,..$ (they are not vectors), and $c_1,c_2,..$ as vector component values, and used the term 'linearly independent', which is not exactly the same as orthogonal. Not sure if the matrix-vector computation is correct either, since the layout of the matrix and the dimension of the vector seems wrong, but I didn't bother checking further.

Comment: This is so helpful! Thank you so much :)